# slick slider проблема с активным слайдом

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Когда ставится параметр `centerMode: true` и слайдер бесконечно прокручивается то у клонированного слайда активность не сразу срабатывает, когда карусель листается то центральный блок принимает стили активности, но если начать листать до последнего то у того блока что клонирован, активность не сразу применяется?

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  autoplay: true,
  dots: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true
});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
    background: #3a8999;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 0.8s;
}
.slick-arrow{
  background: #000!important; 
}
.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-current {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.js"></script>

<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Не ужели ни кто не знает((((

Comment: Если знание ангельского позволяет, можно попробовать поискать баг среди известных или даже задать там свой вопрос, разработчики slick-slider-а довольно активно подключаются к обсуждениям и хорошо знают свой код https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/search?q=centerMode&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Не скажу что они на высоте но искал я там и даже человек один задавал вопрос такой же не так давно https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2825 увы пока ни кто не ответил(((, вот и написал сюда взяв от туда пример, этот баг я давно заметил.

Comment: О, уже ответили, сейчас попробую тот вариант как там

Comment: Супер) Даже не думал, что так забавно получится) Я даже вроде бы и не при чём, а вопрос висевший два дня без ответа на конкурсе решился :D

Comment: да не, сегодня только на конкурс кинул)) и сам офигел что нашел решение))) Но вы если бы не вы я б еще долго не лез в гит, так как думал бы что так быстро там не ответят на этот вопрос)))

Comment: так как в итоге, то решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот исправленный ответ

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  autoplay: true,
  dots: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true
});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
    background: #3a8999;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 0.8s;
}
.slick-arrow{
  background: #000!important; 
}
.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-center {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.js"></script>

<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>
```